# height 100 and iframe = Two scroll bar

Tags: css, height

I have a this :

```
<div style="height:100%">
<div id="menu" style="height:30px;width:100%">Ouhlala</div>
<iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" height="100%" src="baba"></iframe>
</div>
```

It's showing me 2 scroll bars. The height of the iframe is 100% but it's finally 100% + 30px. I don't know how to resolve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) like this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="menu" style="height:30px;width:100%">Ouhlala</div>
  <iframe frameborder="0" src="baba"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container iframe{
   height:calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

The bad about this maybe is compatibility <sub>[check it here](http://caniuse.com/calc)</sub>